# For the multivariate normal model, why is jeffreys' prior distribution not a probability density?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

For the multivariate normal model, Jeffreys' rule for generating a prior distribution on `(theta, sigma)` gives `p_j(theta, sigma) proportional to |sigma|^{-(p+2)/2}.`

My book notes in a footnote that `p_j` cannot actually be a probability density for `theta, sigma.` Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "improper", meaning it doesn't integrate to 1 as probability distributions have to do.  For example, the marginal density with respect to theta is just a constant, whose integral over the real line is infinite.  It's OK to use improper distributions as priors in Bayesian inference, as long as the posterior is a proper probability distribution.